# Why does my list only keep the last line after looping?

Tags: python

```
def main():
    row = 5
    col = 3
    count = 0
    board = list([[""]*col]*row)
    for i in range(0,row):
        for n in range(0,col):
            board[i][n] = str(count)
            print board[i][n] , count, i, n
            count+=1

    print board
main()
```

When I run this code, I expect my list to be :

```
[[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[9,10,11],[12,13,14]]
```

and when I print the individual indices inside the loop, it assigns properly but after exiting the loop, I fine the output ends up being

```
[[12,13,14],[12,13,14],[12,13,14],[12,13,14],[12,13,14]]
```

Comment: `board = list([[""]*col]*row)` is a well-known aliasing bug. Rather than multiple distinct rows, you just have multiple references to a single row.

Comment: @JohnColeman How could I change it in order to fix the error?

Comment: Read the other question -- this is a duplicate and will likely be closed as such within another minute or two

Comment: Do `[[""]*col for i in range(row)]`. The duplicate question John mentions explains why.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this line

```
board = list([[""]*col]*row)
```

with

```
board = [[0 for x in range(col)] for y in range(row)]
```

This change makes the code work for me.